# Pointer to pointer address in C

Tags: c, pointers

What happens if I do this?
Pointer p points to the address memory of q but what happens when I put 10 in *p?

```
int *p, *q = malloc(4);
p = &q;
*p = 10;
```

Comment: `p = &q;` should at least give a compiler warning for a conversion from `int**` to `int*`

Comment: I'll try when home thanks I'll let you know

Comment: What do you expect to happen? Do you plan to access `*q` afterwards? How do you plan to free the memory returned by `malloc` after you have corrupted `q`'s memory?

Comment: Undefined behavior happens on account of accessing `q`, an `int *`, via `*p`, an lvalue of type `int`.  Colloquially, that is a violation of the so-called "strict aliasing rule".  It is also possible for the size of your `int`s to be larger than 4 bytes, in which case *any* access to `q` will produce UB.  Do not make assumptions about the sizes of your data types: use `sizeof` where you need a size that is not specified by the language.

Comment: I suspect the code you intended to write is `int *p, *q = malloc(sizeof *q); p = q; *p = 10`, so that `p` does not "point to the address memory of q" but instead `p` contains the same value as `q`, which is an address.  After the assignment, `p` and `q` both point to the same location, and the value at that address is `10`.  You could also write: `int **p, *q; p = &q; *p = malloc(sizeof(int)); *q = 10;`

Comment: Thank you all this code was just an example anyway I've just tried and I get a warning from compiler but when I do *p = 10; am I changine the number of the address of q?

Comment: @WilliamPursell no I exaclty wanted p to point to the address memory of q, my question is am I changing the address of q when doing *p = 10; ?

Comment: If `p == &q`, then `*p = 10` is the same as `q = 10`, which is (almost certainly) an error.  But if you have `int **p = &q`, then `**p = 10` assigns 10 to the memory location addressed by `q`.  But if `q` is of type `int *`, then `int *p = &q` is an error, and it doesn't make any sense to ask about how it behaves.

Comment: Again, you are producing *undefined behavior*.  What that means in any particular instance is *undefined*.  However, the language does not provide any defined mechanism for changing the address of an object.  But consider this analogy: suppose I give you my business card, which has my e-mail address printed on it.  Now suppose you scratch out that address and write a different one on the card.  If you send e-mail to the modified address, do you expect it to reach me?  Of course not.  You have not changed my address, but only your record of it.

Comment: It is not possible for you to change the address of the memory block returned by `malloc`. There are well-defined things you could do that would make `q` *not point to that block anymore*, but the block itself stays put.

Comment: If p points to q  and you do *p=10 then q now contains the number 10. Addresses are just numbers, pointers are just ints, more or less.